# Selecting specific column in each row from array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to select specific column elements for each row of a numpy array. For example, in the following example:

```
In [1]: a = np.random.random((3,2))
Out[1]: 
array([[ 0.75670668,  0.1283942 ],
       [ 0.51326555,  0.59378083],
       [ 0.03219789,  0.53612603]])
```

I would like to select the first element of the first row, the second element of the second row, and the first element of the third row. So I tried to do the following:

```
In [2]: b = np.array([0,1,0])

In [3]: a[:,b]
```

But this produces the following output:

```
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0.75670668,  0.1283942 ,  0.75670668],
       [ 0.51326555,  0.59378083,  0.51326555],
       [ 0.03219789,  0.53612603,  0.03219789]])
```

which clearly is not what I am looking for. Is there an easy way to do what I would like to do without using loops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
a[np.arange(3), (0,1,0)]
```

in your example above.

Comment: Indeed. *Slicing* preserves the given axis as is whereas what you wanted along both dimensions is called *fancy indexing* in the documentation.

Comment: Right. For example, `a[0:2,0:2]` and `a[[0,1],[0,1]]` return different things.

Answer (score 3):

OK, just to clarify here, lets do a simple example

```
A=diag(arange(0,10,1))
```

gives

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]])
```

then

```
A[0][0:4]
```

gives

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0])
```

that is first row, elements 0 to 3. But

```
A[0:4][1]
```

doesn't give the first 4 rows, the 2nd element in each. Instead we get

```
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

i.e the entire 2nd column.

```
A[0:4,1]
```

gives

```
array([0, 1, 0, 0])
```

I'm sure there is a very good reason for this and which makes perfect sense to programmers
but for those of us uninitiated in that great religion it can be quite confusing.

Comment: A[0:4] creates a new array of shape (4,10). With A[0:4,y], you're asking for the second dimension of the array, whereas for A[0:4][x], you're asking for the first dimension of the new array ! You can write it A[0:4,:][1,:] if it helps you see when are asking for dim 1 or dim 2

Comment: Using diag ended up making this more confusing for yourself and others, because actually `A[0:4][1]` gave you the second *row*, not the second column.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer so much as an attempt to document this a bit.  For the answer above, we would have:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array(range(6))
>>> A
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> A.shape = (3,2)
>>> A
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
>>> A[(0,1,2),(0,1,0)]
array([0, 3, 4])
```

Specifying a list (or tuple) of individual row and column coordinates allows *fancy indexing* of the array.  The first example in the comment looks similar at first, but the indices are slices.  They don't extend over the whole range, and the *shape* of the array that is returned is different:

```
>>> A[0:2,0:2]
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
```

For the second example in the comment

```
>>> A[[0,1],[0,1]]
array([0, 3])
```

So it seems that slices are different, but except for that, regardless of how indices are constructed, you can specify a tuple or list of (x-values, y-values), and recover those specific elements from the array.